# Web pages getting horizontal scrollable

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

In my angular project I am using angular calendars but as soon as I login, my website gets horizontal scrollable and before login it does not get scrollable .What can be the reasons for this? I don't want my screen to get scrollable. Bootstrap is being used .

Comment: Is it possible that you are using `row`s and forgot to put a `container` around it? Then the row will be `100% + 40px` or something.

Comment: @Pieterjan yes looked into it but no that isnt resolving this issue

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Angular but, if you are using custom css then try `overflow-x: hidden;`
or check if any `div` width is mismatched with other elements.

That's how i solved my Problems. Hope so this helps you.

Comment: yes overflow-x hidden works but I want to know why is that happening because everywhere i checked div width wasn't getting mismatched..

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
html, body {
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: please dont repeat the answers..see the above comment ..

Comment: I don't see exact similarities of my answer with others comments and answers :) However, answers could have some sort of similarities anyway :)